# Event not triggered out of document.ready function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger some event in jquery. My trigger functionality is outside of document.ready function. Its not working. If I put the code inside document.ready function its working.

Some other events triggered even they are outside of document.ready function.

Please let me clear the functionality that why some events working only inside document.ready function.

Thanks

Comment: Which events? Which triggers? Add your code to your question.

Comment: I have a button click event. When I click the button click event is not firing

Comment: It's impossible to tell what could be wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: Generally  in some situations outside of document.ready some events triggered but some other situations its not working.  why ?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers execute all JS immediately when it is encountered, even when the page isn't finished loading. In affect, you should expect that when your JS executes, some or all of the DOM is still not available yet as it still is downloading from the server.

Attaching an event handler to elements only works if those elements already exist in the DOM and can therefore be selected at the moment that you are attempting to attach them. In affect, issuing the command `$('.some_element_not_yet_loaded').click(function(){alert('Element Clicked')})` is a no-op because the selector (`.some_element_not_yet_loaded`) doesn't match anything.

The only way to ensure that the elements to which you are attempting to attach handlers exist in the DOM, is to wait until the document.ready event is fired (this event isn't fired until the DOM is indeed done loading and is actually ready).

The reason why you are seeing inconsistent behavior is because this is a classic race condition -- based on how fast or slow the DOM loads from the server and is initialized by the browser determines which elements are present at the time your JS executes. You can, to some extent, cheat by moving your JS to the very bottom of the page, but because the DOM is initialized asynchronously from the execution of the JS, even that can occasionally cause problems. It is therefore best to just put all of your JS initialization code in the document.ready event to completely ensure that the DOM is fully loaded and ready.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation Robert Lee